# Selenium dynamic HTML file

Tags: selenium, java

Hello I'm having a slight issue. I'm using selenium to make a report through ExtentReport which saves a HTML file. I want to be able to save this file dynamically.

This is the code im currently using.

```
report = new ExtentReports("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/ExtentReport/ExtentReport.html" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Adding System.CurrentTimeMills kind of works as it saves it but it ends up being ExtentReport.html1919191919191919191 which works.

The problem that I have is that after I run my selenium test I want it to navigate to the folder and open the HTML as soon as the test is over.

If I use currentTime then I can't open the file as it is made and called about a minute inbetween giving different file names.

This is the code I use to call it after the test is over.

```
String Path ="file:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/ExtentReport/ExtentReport.html" + System.currentTimeMillis();
driver.get(Path);
```

How can I save my html file dynamically whilst still being able to call it later on during my script to open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the filename as a variable. Then pass the variable to the constructor, and also pass it to whatever code needs to open the file later.

```
String reportFileName = "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/ExtentReport/ExtentReport.html" + System.currentTimeMillis());

report = new ExtentReports(reportFileName);

...
```

Also, it might be better to put the timestamp before the extension:

```
String reportFileName = "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/ExtentReport/ExtentReport" + System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".html";
```

That way, if you want to open the file with a browser or other program, the program will understand how to open it.

Comment: Thank you. Worked flawlessly. Didn't realize I could just save the file as a variable

Had an issue calling it but I solved it.

Thank you very much dale!

    driver.get("file://"+reportFileName);